# In scala, how to unbox different Java wrappers of numerical types

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using Apache Spark SQL's SqlParser.parseExpression function to read complex values & expressions from a string.
The parser works properly, but I only have 1 problem: all the numerical evaluation results are boxed (as subclasses of java.lang.Number), and they cannot be typecast into any other compatible numerical type (e.g. java.lang.Double cannot be cast to Int), since the typecast parameter is generated dynamically, I have to write a very long pattern match to unbox each boxed type respectively, is there a short function that I can use to automatically unbox any boxed number?

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.Number` has methods such as `intValue()` and `doubleValue()` for each primitive numeric type.

Instead of pattern matching or casting, you can retrieve the integer value of a `Number` by just calling the `intValue()` method.

If you really want to use pattern matching, then you can use the following:

```
val x: java.lang.Number = new java.lang.Double(5)
(x: Any) match {
  case d: Double => "this is a double"
  case i: Int => "this is an int"
  case _ => "this is something else"
}
// returns "this is a double"
```

Such a pattern match is still quite long, however you could check de documentation (or source) of SqlParser.parseExpression to see what numeric types it may return (e.g. perhaps it only returns Double and Long).